# debian KVM - network bonding fails with vlan and bridge

Tags: debian, kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge

i have a Debian 6 system configured with 2 NICs

these NICs are used on a bond (bond0) which is used by bridge that require to use VLAN.

i can get connection between guests running on VLAN10 but it is not possible to access the host (10.1.10.3) from any guest for instance.

as i am no expert in networking - i am simply setting up a small lab - could i please ask for some guidance on this issue?

if it is necessary further info please let me know.

thanks a lot

system installed:

```
cat /etc/debian_version 
6.0.7
```

kernel in use:

```
uname -r
3.2.0-0.bpo.4-amd64
```

ethernet controllers

```
lspci | grep -i ether
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
06:01.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8169 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
```

.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

# bond0 network interface
auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
        pre-down ethtool -s $IFACE wol g
        bond-slaves eth0 eth1
        bond-primary eth0
        bond-mode 1
        bond-miimon 100
        bond-downdelay 200
        bond-updelay 200

auto virbr1
iface virbr1 inet static
        address 192.168.1.3
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-search home.brain
        dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8
        bridge_ports bond0
        bridge_stp off       # disable Spanning Tree Protocol
        bridge_waitport 0    # no delay before a port becomes available
        bridge_fd 0          # no forwarding delay
        ## default bridge can not have it own hardware value
        ## it has to have the same MAC as the bond
        ## hwaddress ether 02:01:02:03:04:11

auto virbr10
iface virbr10 inet static
        address 10.1.10.3
        broadcast 10.1.10.255
        netmask 255.255.255.0
#        gateway 10.1.10.1
        dns-search mngt.brain
        dns-nameservers 10.1.10.253
        vlan-raw-device bond0
        bridge_ports bond0.10
        bridge_stp off       # disable Spanning Tree Protocol
        bridge_waitport 0    # no delay before a port becomes available
        bridge_fd 0          # no forwarding delay
        hwaddress ether 02:01:02:03:04:12


auto bond0.20
iface bond0.20 inet manual

auto virbr20
iface virbr20 inet static
        address 10.1.20.3
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 10.1.20.255
        network 10.1.20.0
#       pre-up brctl addbr virbr20
        bridge_ports bond0.20
        bridge_stp off       # disable Spanning Tree Protocol
        bridge_waitport 0    # no delay before a port becomes available
        bridge_fd 0          # no forwarding delay
        hwaddress ether 02:01:02:03:04:13
```

Comment: is it necessary to provide further info enable somebody to assist me with this problem?